# Alerts conditional on model validation

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, validation, model, alert

I have an `Picture` model with various validations:

```
  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :caption, presence: true
  validates :image, presence: true
  validates :price, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 1, less_than_or_equal_to: 1000 }
  validates_size_of :tag_list, :minimum => 3, :message => "please add at least three tags"
```

The tag list has to be submitted in a specific format: at least three tags, separated by a comma and a space: eg `foo, bar, cats`

I want to have an alert that tells the user to "please wait, we're uploading your image" - but only AFTER the model has passed ALL of the validations ( before the `.save` in the controller)

Is there a way of doing this in the controller, which I'd prefer, or do I have to use some javascript like:

```
$("form#new_picture").on("submit", function () {
    if LOTS OF HORRIBLE REGEX ON FORM FIELDS {
      MESSAGE HERE
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  });
```

OR Is there a way of doing this in the model, as part of an `after_validation` callback?

Any suggestions much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would build a JS function to extract the fields that I want to be validated.

Then create a custom AJAX controller action, which:

- instantiates a new object with given params
- call valid? on it without saving it

Then:

- On failure, update the form with error messages
- On success, I would return a custom ajax response to display the alert and start POSTing the real object.

Answer (score 0):

I've realised that this isn't really possible through through the model or controller, and resorted to a combination of three validation processes:

- Validations in the model
- The [simpleform client side validations gem](https://github.com/DockYard/client_side_validations-simple_form) - this is v good, it tests validity the moment a form field loses focus - "real time" validation.
- And some [additional javascript](http://jsfiddle.net/jgwhite/Eqjh9/) to alert with popups and errors, pasted below.

Hopefully this makes the form virtually un-submittable without the user knowing what's missing.

THE JS SOLUTION

FORM

```
<form id="new_pic" novalidate>
  <p><input type="file" name="file" required></p>
  <p><input type="string" name="name" placeholder="Name" required></p>
  <p><input type="string" name="tags" placeholder="Tags" data-validation="validateTags"></textarea></p>
  <p><textarea name="description" data-validation="validateDescription"></textarea></p>
  <p><button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

JS

```
var Validator = function(form) {
  this.form = $(form);
}
$.extend(Validator.prototype, {
  valid: function() {
    var self = this;

    this.errors = {};

    this.form.find('[required]').each(function() {
      self.validateRequired($(this));
    });

    this.form.find('[data-validation]').each(function() {
      var el = $(this),
          method = el.data('validation');

      self[method].call(self, el);
    });

    return $.isEmptyObject(this.errors);
  },

  validateRequired: function(input) {
    if (input.val() === '') {
      this.addError(input, 'is required');
    }
  },

  validateDescription: function(input) {
    if (input.val().length < 64) {
      this.addError(input, 'must be at least 64 characters');
    }
  },

  validateTags: function(input) {
    var tags = input.val().split(/, ?/);

    if (tags.length < 3) {
      this.addError(input, 'must have at least 3 tags');
    }
  },

  addError: function(input, error) {
    var name = input.attr('name');
    this.errors[name] = this.errors[name] || [];
    this.errors[name].push(error);
    input.after('<span class="error">' + error + '</span>');
  }
});

$('form#new_pic').on('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var form = $(this),
      validator = new Validator(form);

  form.find('.error').remove();

  if (validator.valid()) {
    // continue with upload
    alert('Go!');
    return true;
  } else {
    // complain
    alert('Stop!');
    return false;
  }
});
```